# Angular2 Router

Tags: angular, leaflet, angular2-routing

So I'm trying Angular2 (following an onlinetutorial).
But I'm having problems with navigating with Router.

inside my component.ts:

```
  foo() {
    this.router.navigate(['/myroute']);
  }

  onMapClick(e) {
    this.router.navigate(['/myroute']);
  }
```

The foo() is triggered from:

```
<a (click)="foo()">test</a>
```

(Just to test the navigation-function.)

The onMapClick-function is click-event from leaflet-lib. I can click on the map and the function triggers. 
But I get:

```
EXCEPTION: Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined
ErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:54
next @ application_ref.js:348
schedulerFn @ async.js:93
SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:234
SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:183
Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:125
Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89
Subject.next @ Subject.js:55
EventEmitter.emit @ async.js:79
NgZone.triggerError @ ng_zone.js:333
onHandleError @ ng_zone.js:294
ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:334
Zone.runTask @ zone.js:169
ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:416
error_handler.js:59 ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
ErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:59
next @ application_ref.js:348
schedulerFn @ async.js:93
SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:234
SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:183
Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:125
Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89
Subject.next @ Subject.js:55
EventEmitter.emit @ async.js:79
NgZone.triggerError @ ng_zone.js:333
onHandleError @ ng_zone.js:294
ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:334
Zone.runTask @ zone.js:169
ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:416
ETC..
```

These functions are right after eachother... Why does one work, but the other not?

This is where I trigger the event:

```
    constructor(
    private router: Router
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.drawMap();
  }

  drawMap() {
    var map = L.map('map').setView([0, 0], 3);

    L.tileLayer('maptiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
      minZoom: 3,
      maxZoom: 4,
      continuousWorld: false,
      noWrap: true,
      crs: L.CRS.Simple,
    }).addTo(map);

    map.on('click', this.onMapClick);
  }
```

Comment: Please post the link to the tutorial.

Comment: https://github.com/bradtraversy/meanauthapp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because inside `onMapClick` function, `this` is not refering to your component. It is refering to the click event, and the event doesn't have a `router` property. Thus, `this.router` becomes `undefined`.

Change: `map.on('click', this.onMapClick);`

to

```
map.on('click', this.onMapClick.bind(this));
```

or

```
map.on('click', ()=>{this.onMapClick();});
```

Comment: The event is just triggering a function. I can remove the event from the argument:
  onMapClick() {
    this.router.navigate(['/myroute']);
  }
still no change, am I thinking wrong? :)

Comment: @alexfyren can you share the code where you trigger this function?

Comment: I'll add to the question ;)

Comment: That worked! :) (the 2nd one)
Is this a typescript-issue? Any tips for things I should read more on? :)
Really good job! Thank you so much!

Comment: @alexfyren It is a scope issue. When you give named functions in the callback like that, `this` will refer to that specific functions instance (in your case the click event of your leaflet-lib). The es6 arrow notation (`()=>`) creates a closure so that this will refer to the outer `this`. I don't know why the first one didn't work but I'll remove it to avoid confusion. And glad I could help :-)

Comment: @alexfyren Haha, no problem :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to inject the router in order to be able to use it

```
constructor(private router:Router) {}
```